# How to change the font size for multiple axes labels (created with host_subplot API)

Tags: matplotlib, font-size, host, multiple-axes

I looked on the internet and absolutely all the examples with multiple axes have the xlabel and ylabel at a default value and quite small

I used the following code to create the axes:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
```

...

```
    ax=[]
    if  twoaxes or threeaxes:
        ax.append(host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes))
        plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)
    else:
        ax.append(fig.add_subplot(111))
    if twoaxes or threeaxes:
        ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
    if threeaxes:
        ax.append(ax[0].twinx())
        offset = 60
        new_fixed_axis = ax[2].get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
        ax[2].axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right", axes=ax[2],offset=(offset, 0))
        ax[2].axis["right"].toggle(all=True)
```

and I tried to change the font size with 3 methods and all failed

1)

```
ax[i].set_xlabel(xlabel, fontsize = fontsize)
```

2)

```
fontd = {'family' : 'serif',
                 'color'  : 'darkred',
                 'weight' : 'normal',
                 'size'   : fontsize,
        }
        ax[i].yaxis.set_label_text(ylabel, fontdict=fontd)
```

and 3)

```
   ax[i].xaxis.get_label().set_fontsize(fontsize)
```

None of the methods worked and given that all the examples so far showed very small font for the axes' labels I suppose that it is either quirky difficult or not possible.  Any idea is welcome at this stage.

I forgot to mention that when the axis is created with

```
  fig.add_subplot(111)
```

all the methods mentioned above work just fine and the font size is changed.

Answer (score 6):

After some digging I found the answer.  I use below simpler example and add two lines that just do what I asked.

The following two lines change the axisartist font

```
    par2.axis["right"].label.set_fontsize(34)
    host.axis["bottom"].label.set_fontsize(34)
```

This is the full example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if 1:

    host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
    plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

    par1 = host.twinx()
    par2 = host.twinx()

    offset = 60
    new_fixed_axis = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis
    par2.axis["right"] = new_fixed_axis(loc="right",
                                        axes=par2,
                                        offset=(offset, 0))

    par2.axis["right"].toggle(all=True)



    host.set_xlim(0, 2)
    host.set_ylim(0, 2)

    host.set_xlabel("Distance")
    host.set_ylabel("Density")
    par1.set_ylabel("Temperature")
    par2.set_ylabel("Velocity")

    p1, = host.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], label="Density")
    p2, = par1.plot([0, 1, 2], [0, 3, 2], label="Temperature")
    p3, = par2.plot([0, 1, 2], [50, 30, 15], label="Velocity")

    par1.set_ylim(0, 4)
    par2.set_ylim(1, 65)

    host.legend()

    host.axis["left"].label.set_color(p1.get_color())

    par1.axis["right"].label.set_color(p2.get_color())
    par2.axis["right"].label.set_color(p3.get_color())
    fontd = {'family' : 'serif',
                 'color'  : 'darkred',
                 'weight' : 'normal',
                 'size'   : 'large',
    }

    #This is the code that changes the font.  
    par2.axis["right"].label.set_fontsize(34)
    host.axis["bottom"].label.set_fontsize(34)


    plt.draw()
    plt.show()
```

The output:

[image: The output:]