# How to change the labels of an axis created with host_subplot (from AxesGrid toolkit)

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes, multiple-axes

The AxesGrid toolkit provides the function `host_subplot`, which makes possible the creation of multiple parallel axis, as show in the code bellow:

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
par2 = host.twiny()
par2.axis["bottom"] = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom", axes=par2, offset=(0, -30) )
par2.axis["bottom"].toggle(all=True)
```

Which creates the following figure:
[image]

Now I would like to change the label of the second x axis added below the image. I tried the following (among other things):

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import host_subplot
import mpl_toolkits.axisartist as AA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
par2 = host.twiny()
par2.axis["bottom"] = par2.get_grid_helper().new_fixed_axis(loc="bottom", axes=par2, offset=(0, -30) )

for item in par2.get_xticklabels(): 
    item.set_text('new label')

par2.axis["bottom"].toggle(all=True)
```

Sadly `par2.get_xticklabels()` does not seem to work as I naively expected (i.e. it does not return the labels of the x axis).

The most similar question I found adressing a similar issua was [How to change the font size for multiple axes labels (created with host_subplot API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28308822/how-to-change-the-font-size-for-multiple-axes-labels-created-with-host-subplot), which changes the font size property (not individual labels attached to the xaxis ticks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one thing I learned while trying to find an answer for this: `IPython` is a ***really good*** helper.

---

Anyway, to get to the point. There seems to be something buggy about setting the text by iterating for each entry via `get_xticklabels()`. 
By assigning with `set_text(my_text)`, even though `my_text` does indeed pass in the `Text` object, for some reason it is not picking it up afterwards.

Case in point:

```
[item.set_text("Some Text") for item in par2.get_xticklabels()]

for item in par2.get_xticklabels():
    print item

# Prints
Text(0,0,'Some Text')
Text(0,0,'Some Text')
Text(0,0,'Some Text')
Text(0,0,'Some Text')
Text(0,0,'Some Text')
Text(0,0,'Some Text')

# plt.show() does not display these changes.
```

**Thankfully** (*and oddly*), **setting the labels** ***works*** **when doing it via** `set_xticklabels()`

```
# Omitting rest of script.

# Set as False or else the top axis also gets these labels.
# Try commenting the line out to view what I mean.
par2.axis["top"].set_visible(False)
par2.set_xticklabels(["THIS", "IS", "PROBABLY", "A", "LITTLE", "BUG"])

plt.show()
```

The figure drawn in this case is what you're looking for:

[image: bottom axis tick labels]

---

To add to the hypothesis of this being a little bug, the output of the same print statement as before returns a similar representation as it did before.

```
for item in par2.get_xticklabels():
    print item

Text(0,0,'THIS')
Text(0,0,'IS')
Text(0,0,'PROBABLY')
Text(0,0,'A')
Text(0,0,'LITTLE')
Text(0,0,'BUG')
```

I am not the best with `matplotlib`, but this just seems iffy. Maybe someone with more knowledge can verify.

Answer (score 1):

Dimitris' answer is awesome! Anyway, I will describe bellow the workaround I finished using (before having his answer). The strategy was to add a new axes over the figure and then hide everything, except the x axis. This solution has the sole advantage of not requiring the use of the AxesGrid framework.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def add_extra_xaxis(fig, x, labels, padding=35):
    """
    Add a x axis bellow the figure (indeed bellow the ax returned by fig.gca()) having the labels
    in the x positions. The axis is added by first adding an entire new axes and the hiding all
    parts, except the xaxis.

     Parameters
    ------------

    fig : Figure
        The figure where to add the xaxis.

    x : list
        List of numbers specifying the x positions.

    labels : list
        List of strings specifying the labels to place in the x positions.

    padding : int
        How much space should be added between the figure and the new x axis bellow it.

     Returns
    ---------

    new_ax : Axes
        Return the axes added to the image.

    """

    # Add some space bellow the figure
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

    # Get current ax
    ax = fig.gca()

    # Add a new ax to the figure
    new_ax = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position())

    # Hide the the plot area and the yaxis
    new_ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    new_ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)

    # Hide spines (unless the boottom one)
    for spinename, spine in new_ax.spines.iteritems():
        if spinename != 'bottom':
            spine.set_visible(False)

    # Set the ....
    new_ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('outward', padding))

    # Change tick labels
    plt.xticks([0] + x, [''] + labels) # the [0] and [''] stuff is to add an empty lable in the first position

    return new_ax


if __name__=='__main__':

    f, _ = plt.subplots()
    add_extra_xaxis(f, [1,3,5,7,10],['Now','it','should', 'work', ''], padding=30)
```

Comment: Nice additional solution, probably best you avoided `AxesGrid` since ***it seems*** it might need some additional debugging.